# How to read data like those stored in the *.epf file

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to read data from a `.epf` file, and the data is like:

```
/instance/org.eclipse.wb.core/design.palette.flyout.width=192
```

I think I can use `Map<String, String>` to store it, but the problem is how to get rid of the `=`, and then put the left part and right part into the `Map`?

Comment: I'm not sure what an EPF file looks like, can you add an example of what a line in the file look like?

Comment: Hi, Joshua, I have already put a line of example in my question:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jarnbjo mentioned, if it conforms to the property file format, you can read the file using the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

If you want to store the data in a map, you can use a string function to get the 2 parts of the data:

```
// Assuming data contains "/instance/org.eclipse.wb.core/design.palette.flyout.width=192"
String[] parts = data.split("=");

// Get the parts
String key = parts[0];   // /instance/org.eclipse.wb.core/design.palette.flyout.width
String value = parts[1]; // 192 

// Or just directly use the map
map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
```

To test beforehand if the string contains an, just use String#contains().

```
if (string.contains("=")) {
    // Split it.
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("String " + string + " does not contain =");
}
```

Comment: Very detailed answer, Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

If the files conform to the property file format, you can read them using the [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

Comment: Got it, jarnbjo. I checked, I think it will work:) Thx